# integer formatting does not work in Python

Tags: python, formatting

I am trying to save my images with the time epoch plus iterating integers like this:

`text_img.save('/content/result/' + epoch + '_%03d' + '.png' , format="png")`

However, the output is something like this:

`16087965_%03d.jpg`

The formatting does not work for some reason. I do not know why.

Comment: What is `_%03d` supposed to give?

Comment: `_001`, `_002`, and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, `'_%03d'` is just a literal string. Since  your code is in a loop, you'll want to provide the loop counter variable to be formatted.

Try something like:

```
import time

for i in range(100):
    epoch = str(int(time.time() / 1000))
    name = '/content/result/' + epoch + '_%03d' % i + '.png'
    text_img.save(name, format='png')
```

Or you can instead achieve the same thing using f-strings:

```
import time

for i in range(100):
    epoch = str(int(time.time() / 1000))
    name = f'/content/result/{epoch}_{i:03}.png'
    text_img.save(name, format='png')
```

Comment: Also, be aware that you can probably move the assignment to `epoch` *before* the loop. I assume the point of the increasing integers is to distinguish files sharing the same timestamp.

Comment: I'm not using the loop anymore. I just want to be able to use this format without it being a literal string..

Comment: Yep, @chepner makes sense. The question didn't provide a lot context so I just put it in the body initially, but I suppose that was the OP's intention.

Comment: @oo92 You need *some* variable (or value). `%03d` doesn't generate an integer itself, it only provides the "instruction" to the `%` operator for how to format an integer *you* provide. That is, `%03d` isn't special to the string, only to the `%` operator which parses the string in order to produce a new string.